# Navigation URL Rules for Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.dll

Tags: url-rewriting

I m using Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.dll for URL ReWritting

I wrote below line of code in web config.

```
<rewrite url="~/Reservation/" to="~/Division.aspx?DIV=5&amp /> 
<rewrite url="~/Tours/ " to="~/Division.aspx?DIV=10/>
```

Here my navigation steps are :
1.From Default.aspx i will click on URL Reservations 
  In Default,aspx  Reservations 
  corresponding code for Reservations in web.config is

< rewrite url="~/Reservation/" to="~/Division.aspx?DIV=5&amp>

---------This is working fine when i will click on link Reservations in Defaul.aspx It is redirecting to Division.aspx with path in browser written as 
http://localhost/Test/Reservation/ .

2.When i will click on link Tours it should redirect to http://localhost/Test/tours/ .
In tours.aspx < a id="hlnav2_0" href="tours/"> Tours
But it is showing http://localhost/Test/Reservation/tours .

how to write rule to get required out put.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the space from "~/Tours/ " may work.